# MATLAB 2013a: sum + squeeze dimension inconsistencies

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, transpose

Please let me try to explain by an example

```
numel_last_a = 1;
numel_last_b = 2

a = rand(2,20,numel_last_a);
b = rand(2,20,numel_last_b);
size(squeeze(sum(a,1)))
size(squeeze(sum(b,1)))
```

in this case, the output will be

```
ans = 1 20
ans = 20 2
```

This means I have to catch the special case where numel_last_x == 1 to apply a transpose operation for consistency with later steps. I'm guessing that there must be a more elegant solution. Can you guys help me out?

Edit: sorry, code was wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following observations are key here:

1. The inconsistency you mention is buried deep into the Matlab language: all arrays are considered to be **at least 2D**. For example, `ndims(pi)` gives `2`.
2. Another rule in Matlab is that all arrays are assumed to have **infinitely many trailing singleton dimensions**. For example, `size(pi,5)` gives `1`.

According to observation 1, [`squeeze`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) won't remove singleton dimensions if doing so would give less than two dimensions. This is mentioned in the documentation:

> `B = squeeze(A)` returns an array `B` with the same elements as `A`, but with all singleton dimensions removed. A singleton dimension is any dimension for which `size(A,dim) = 1`. **Two-dimensional arrays are unaffected by `squeeze`; if `A` is a row or column vector or a scalar (1-by-1) value, then `B = A`**.

If you want to get rid of the **first** singleton, you can exploit observation 2 and use [`reshape`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
numel_last_a = 1;
numel_last_b = 2;
a = rand(2,20,numel_last_a);
b = rand(2,20,numel_last_b);
as = reshape(sum(a,1), size(a,2), size(a,3));
bs = reshape(sum(b,1), size(b,2), size(b,3));
size(as)
size(bs)
```

gives

```
ans =
    20     1
ans =
    20     2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use shiftdim instead of squeeze

```
numel_last_a = 1;
numel_last_b = 2;

a = rand(2,20,numel_last_a);
b = rand(2,20,numel_last_b);
size(shiftdim(sum(a,1)))
size(shiftdim(sum(b,1)))
ans =

    20     1


ans =

    20     2
```